# Codewars: Remote Control Virtual Keyboard

Tags: object-oriented, programming-challenge, typescript, pathfinding, coordinate-system

This is my solution to the Codewars problem [TV Remote (symbols)](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5b3077019212cbf803000057).

**Description**

In short, you are given a virtual keyboard with 3 modes between which can be switched by pressing the `Shift` button on the virtual keyboard.

You have to navigate using only arrow buttons (`up`, `right`, `down`, `left`) and an `OK`-button to press the currently selected button. Wraparound is possible.

The challenge is to find the shortest sequence of button presses with which you can write a given `string` (ignoring optimizations such as prematurely switching Mode).

**Questions**

1. Is it correct to make methods which don't rely on the internal state
   (such as `calculateMoves`) `static`?  Or is it recommended to
   effectively duplicate its functionality (for `row` and `col` each)
   and use its internal state?
2. Since I'm not all too experienced with OOP, did I break any common 
   conventions?

**Code**

```js
type Coords = { row: number, col: number }

function mod(a: number, b: number): number {
  return ((a % b) + b) % b
}

class TvRemote {
  private static readonly ModeButton = 'aA#'
  private static readonly Mode = [
    // Mode1 = [0]
    [
      'abcde123'.split(''),
      'fghij456'.split(''),
      'klmno789'.split(''),
      'pqrst.@0'.split(''),
      'uvwxyz_/'.split(''),
      [TvRemote.ModeButton, ' ', , , , , , ,]
    ],
    // Mode2 = [1]
    [
      'ABCDE123'.split(''),
      'FGHIJ456'.split(''),
      'KLMNO789'.split(''),
      'PQRST.@0'.split(''),
      'UVWXYZ_/'.split(''),
      [TvRemote.ModeButton, ' ', , , , , , ,]
    ],
    // Mode3 = [2]
    [
      `^~?!\'"()`.split(''),
      '-:;+&%*='.split(''),
      '<>€£$¥¤\\'.split(''),
      '[]{},.@§'.split(''),
      ['#', '¿', '¡', , , , '_', '/'],
      [TvRemote.ModeButton, ' ', , , , , , ,]
    ]
  ]
  private static readonly NumRows = 6
  private static readonly NumCols = 8

  private currRow = 0
  private currCol = 0
  private currModeIndex = 0
  private buttonPresses = 0

  public getButtonPresses (): number {
    return this.buttonPresses
  }

  public write (string: string): void {
    for (const char of string) {
      this.moveToChar(char)
      this.pressButton()
    }
  }

  private currentMode(): string[][] {
    return TvRemote.Mode[this.currModeIndex]
  }

  private currentChar(): string {
    return this.currentMode()[this.currRow][this.currCol]
  }

  private moveToChar (char: string): void {
    this.switchToCorrectMode(char)

    const { row, col } = this.getCoordinates(char)
    const moveRowsBy = TvRemote.calculateMoves(this.currRow, row, TvRemote.NumRows)
    const moveColsBy = TvRemote.calculateMoves(this.currCol, col, TvRemote.NumCols)

    this.move(moveRowsBy, moveColsBy)
  }

  private switchToCorrectMode (char: string): void {
    if (this.existsInCurrentMode(char)) return

    for (let i = 0; i < TvRemote.Mode.length - 1; i++) {
      if (!this.existsInCurrentMode(TvRemote.ModeButton) && TvRemote.Mode.length > 1) {
        throw new Error('Missing button to switch modes')
      }

      this.moveToChar(TvRemote.ModeButton)
      this.pressButton()

      if (this.existsInCurrentMode(char)) {
        return this.moveToChar(char)
      }
    }

    throw new Error(`Character "${char}" does not exist on keyboard`)
  }

  private static calculateMoves (curr: number, target: number, maxNum: number): number {
    // positive: right for x, down for y
    const movePos = (maxNum + target - curr) % maxNum
    const moveNeg = - (maxNum + curr - target) % maxNum

    return Math.abs(movePos) <= Math.abs(moveNeg) ? movePos : moveNeg
  }

  private move (moveRowsBy: number, moveColsBy: number): void {
    this.currRow = mod(this.currRow + moveRowsBy, TvRemote.NumRows)
    this.buttonPresses += Math.abs(moveRowsBy)

    this.currCol = mod(this.currCol + moveColsBy, TvRemote.NumCols)
    this.buttonPresses += Math.abs(moveColsBy)
  }

  private pressButton(): void {
    this.buttonPresses++
    const currChar = this.currentChar()

    console.log(currChar)
    if (currChar === TvRemote.ModeButton) {
      this.currModeIndex = mod(this.currModeIndex + 1, TvRemote.Mode.length)
    }
  }

  private existsInCurrentMode (char: string): boolean {
    const { row , col } = this.getCoordinates(char)
    return row !== -1 && col !== -1
  }

  private getCoordinates (char: string): Coords {
    let col = -1
    let row = this.currentMode().findIndex(rowEntries => {
      col = rowEntries.indexOf(char)
      return col !== -1
    })

    return { row, col }
  }
}
```

**Example output**

Calling `.write('Too Easy?')` should result in `71` button presses. 
See [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/5b3077019212cbf803000057#example) for a detailed explanation.